# Adobe Animate CC file not playing when uploaded to server

Tags: html5-canvas, animate-cc

I have some basic animate CC files that work when tested locally using a browser or preview in Dreamweaver; but when uploaded to my server does not play.
The files are all adapted from the same "template" which was the first animation I created which does work when uploaded. The output files are HTML5 canvas.

Not sure why the other files will not play. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the URL to the working files and then below the problem one:
http://www.robertfitzroyacademy.com/rfa-w.html (portal URL- I am testing reception and year 1)
http://www.robertfitzroyacademy.com/rfaworld-reception.html (working animation)
http://www.robertfitzroyacademy.com/rfaworld-year1.html (problem animation)

I also have a dropbox with the files in: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gq5v6m696jgtzx/HTML5%20animation%20issue.zip?dl=0

Many thanks in advance for any help you can give.
Hanniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the answer, I hadn't uploaded all the linked image files. Even though I had no new images as such, each time I generated a new fla file from the original it created a new image file linked to the new file.

Once I uploaded all the associated files the animation started playing.